# Writing to socket causes segmentation fault if string array is copied

Tags: c, string, sockets, segmentation-fault

I am writing a C language program for a data communication class. I am trying to implement selective reject between a client and a server. The message is hamming encoded.

In my client, I create a char array called hamming_buffer which contains the frame with headers,control characters and the encoded data. In order to implement the selective reject, I have to keep track of some number of frames. To do this, I save the frames into an array of string called window_buffer.

```
  strcpy(frame_buffer,sync); //make the first two characters in the frame SYNC  
  strcpy(frame_buffer+8,sync);
  char *window_buffer[DEFAULT_FRAME_SIZE]; //default frame size is 64, global to main
  char frame_buffer[DEFAULT_FRAME_SIZE*8]={'0'}
  ...
  char hamming_buffer[hammingBytesInData*8+24]; //declared within the innermost loop
```

When I try to save my current frame and then write to the socket, I get a segmentation fault

```
//window_buffer[frame_counter%DEFAULT_WINDOW_SIZE]=hamming_buffer; //add hamming buffer to window_buffer
//memcpy(window_buffer[frame_counter%DEFAULT_WINDOW_SIZE],hamming_buffer,(int)sizeof(hamming_buffer)/sizeof(char));
 strncpy(window_buffer[frame_counter%DEFAULT_WINDOW_SIZE],hamming_buffer,sizeof(hamming_buffer)/sizeof(hamming_buffer[0]));
 //some code to introduce errors into the frame
 write(sockfd,hamming_buffer,(sizeof(hamming_buffer)/sizeof(hamming_buffer[0])));
```

I noticed that when I remove any attempts to copy the hamming buffer, I don't get any issues, but when I try to copy I get a segmentation fault when I try to write.

I've dealt with similar issues in this project, but this one has me scratching my head. My best guess is that I am somehow clobbering the memory that is being used by hamming_buffer when filling the window_buffer.

Any what I'm doing wrong here.

I need my code to be able to write to the socket without there being a segmentation fault.

Comment: Show how you set the `window_buffer` entries. At a guess, you may be trying to write to an uninitialised pointer. Very difficult to debug incomplete code. Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: How I fill in the window buffer is already included in the second block of code. Do you mean how I fill in that data in the first place (i.e. how I'm filling the hamming buffer?)

Comment: A debugger should tell you exactly which line caused the segfault, and let you check any variable values.

Comment: `window_buffer[index]` is a `char *`. That `char *` needs to point to a valid memory buffer. So where does that memory buffer come from?

Comment: I know which line is causing the segmentation fault, it's the write function. Can you recommend a debugger that works on Ubuntu? This project utilizes a few Linux libraries.

Comment: the window_buffer is filled as seen here by the hamming_buffer. The hamming buffer is filled immediately after being declared by memcpy(hamming_buffer,frame_buffer,24); The frame_buffer is declared as frame_buffer[DEFAULT_WINDOW_SIZE*8]={'0'} it contains all the same data as the hamming_buffer. The hamming_buffer is built for the case where the data does not match the DEFAULT_DATA_SIZE. So it might actually be redundant.

Comment: I use `gdb` on Ubuntu when I use `gcc`. It works pretty much anywhere. Sometimes I use LLVM, which has `lldb`.

Comment: "the window_buffer is filled as seen here by the hamming_buffer.". That's the problem. That code is totally wrong. You are passing a `char *` to the `strncpy`. That is *not* a char buffer (as it seems you have not initialised those pointers). You need to set `window_buffer[frame_counter%DEFAULT_WINDOW_SIZE]` to first point to a valid memory buffer. Suggest you review C pointers and memory management.

Comment: I have some commented out attempt to fill the memory using window_buffer[frame_counter%DEFAULT_WINDOW_SIZE]=hamming_buffer; This gives me the same problem. Do I need to do something initialize valid memory?

Comment: If you are asking these questions then you need to go back to C basics and start with much simpler examples. Stackoverflow is not a good place to teach such basics. A C text book/tutorial is your better option.

Comment: Doesn't `sizeof(hamming_buffer)/sizeof(hamming_buffer[0])` _logically_ mean "the number of elements in `hamming_buffer`" (total size/size of one element) rather than some size in bytes? But mathematically isn't `sizeof(hamming_buffer)/sizeof(hamming_buffer[0])` the same as `sizeof(hamming_buffer)` because it is an array of `char` (and `sizeof(char)` is necessarily always 1)? If you want to write the _whole_ `hamming_buffer` in your `strncpy()` and `write()`, it is just `sizeof(hamming_buffer)` bytes.

Comment: My class was given this assignment with no prerequisite understanding of C (i.e. we have to do it whether or not we know the first thing about c). I did happen to take a C basics course, but this depth of memory allocation was not covered. So I do apologize is my questions seem entirely too basic for stack overflow.

Comment: the sizeof(hamming_buffer) will only return the size of a char. sizeof(hamming_buffer)/sizeof(hamming_buffer[0]) is what will give the number of elements in the array.

Comment: My point is that [`strncpy()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy) and [`write()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write) ask for the _number of bytes_, not the number of array elements. The number of array elements is useless information for these functions because they have no way of knowing the size of each element. `sizeof(hamming_buffer)` would return whatever `hammingBytesInData*8+24` evaluates to, because that's what you defined it as. You get a segfault because you're writing where you shouldn't (suggesting the destination is wrong), but eventually you also need to get the size right.

Comment: Since it is a char array and chars are 1 byte, the number of elements is the number of bytes being sent. So it shouldn't directly be an issue for the write, but I can see where that might cause some issues with copy into the window buffer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a 64-long array of char *
You did not allocate any space to store the buffer where the pointer can point to. If the array is local, it's stored in the stack and uninitialized, so pointer values are undefined. If the array is static or external, then all of them are zero.
Ideally, you would get a segmentation fault right when trying to copy the first byte. But you are probably copying onto a page you have privilege to write to, corrupting other data or even the code itself, if writable and not separate from data. Anyway, when you try to send the possibly corrupted frame with your possibly corrupted code, you trigger the segmentation fault.

You must first assign memory for the frames you want to store. There are three choices:

1. You malloc a space the same length as the frame (possibly freeing first or just realloc-ating older frame space).
2. You declare a two-dimensional array with a suitable size for the max frame length you wsnt to handle. Easy, but less elastic and wasting memory. Also not a good idea if it's an automatic variable in the stack.
3. You malloc the space for the buffer and then just assign it to an array position instead of copying. This is the most optimal way, if suitable to your needs.

Comment: This is similar to another bug I had to fix with this project. On my server I have to create a buffer to hold frames. However in this case, it was the individual frames that had to be malloc'd. I was trying to avoid doing that again, but it looks like I might be in that boat.

Comment: Each `window_buffer` element is a pointer to `char`. You have to allocate a buffer for each of these, otherwise you're writing where you shouldn't when you try to write to them.